# Tomcat multiple domains Jelastic tutorial

Tags: tomcat, nginx, jelastic

I've tried to follow the Jelastic 'multiple domains' tutorial, but got no success.

```
http://docs.jelastic.com/multiple-domains2
```

I deployed two applications to different contexts, mapped the cname in DNS record, edited the server.xml and added the Host entries. But i'm getting an error when trying to access:

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.4.0
```

Here are my server.xml entries:

```
  <Host name="urbanistico.com.br" appBase="webapps/urbanistico" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>urbanistico.com.br</Alias>
    <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/urbanistico" />
  </Host>

  <Host name="smarttrade.com.br" appBase="webapps/st" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>smarttrade.com.br</Alias>
    <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/st" />
  </Host>
```

The applications are deployed as:

```
 webapps/urbanistico
 webapps/st
```

Does anyone knows why is this happening. I've double checked the configuration and it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced manual described at http://docs.jelastic.com/multiple-domains2.
Your settings look fine for me. You binned your domains in dashboard with www. or without it?

You can submit a support ticket to your hosting provider, they helps you for sure.
[image]